# Animate a div from bottom to top with css

Tags: html, css

I need to animate a div going from bottom to top.
This is the situation:
I have a thumbnail that includes the title and description of a movie inside of it. I want to hide the description and only show it when the user hovers the mouse on it.

I tried resizing the height of the container but you can't animate it when the value is set to "auto", and i can't provide an specific size for it because the title may vary for each movie.
And as a lot of you may know, you can't animate from bottom to top using the "bottom" and "top" properties.

This is the html:

```
<div class="thumbnail-component">
  <img class="thumbnail-component__background" src="background.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="thumbnail-component__gradient"></div>
  <div class="text">

    <div class="text__content">
        <p class="text__title">The movie title</p>
        <div class="text__separator"></div>
        <p class="text__description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <p class="text__author">Published by Author</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is an image of what i'm trying to accomplish:

[image: https://imgur.com/Ddkj5oI]

I'm honestly completely lost, i think i tried everything i know.
Sorry for my not too great english.

Comment: Any CSS to show?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Show Card description on Card hover

**Completely flexible and responsive**
No hard-coded or arbitrary heights, no JS involved.

[image: On hover show card description using CSS]

Basically,

- translateY the title to `-100%`, on hover animate to `0`
- Wrap both title and content into a DIV (i.e: `.anim`)
- translateY `.anim` to `+100%`, and on hover animate it to `0`

Open the example in full page to see what happens and how it works:

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

.thumb {
  width: 140px;
  background: #eee;
}

.anim {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.title {
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.author {
  color: blue;
}

/* ANIMATE */

.thumb:hover .anim,
.thumb:hover .title {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb">
  <div class="anim">
    <div class="title">The movie even longer title</div>
    <div class="description">
      Text lenghts of Title and Author or even Description do not matter. They will all perfectly accommodate into .thumb on hover
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="author">Published by super long some Author</div>
</div>
```

#### Flexbox Grid!

The real-case proof of concept example:

```css
/*QuickReset*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font: 14px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

.grid-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 33.333%;
  color: #fff;
}

.thumb-gradient,
.thumb-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.thumb-gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.56) 100%);
}

.thumb-anim {
  margin-top: auto;  /* pushes all content to bottom */
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.thumb-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.thumb-description {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

.thumb-author {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}


/* ANIMATE */

.thumb:hover .thumb-anim {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.thumb:hover .thumb-title {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.thumb:hover .thumb-description {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-3">

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        Text lenghts of Title and Author or even Description do not matter. They will all perfectly accommodate into .thumb on hover
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Published by super long some Author</div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/400/300" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        The row heights are dictated by the tallest in the horizontal group
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Published</div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/230/300" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title a super long title here</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus facilis beatae, numquam aliquam eveniet. Iure porro provident itaque hic quae tempora. Quaerat doloribus dolore facilis similique, soluta asperiores quas sapiente.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Published by super long some Author</div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/270/300" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        Text lenghts of Title and Author or even Description do not matter. They will all perfectly accommodate into .thumb on hover
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Published by super long some Author</div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/250/370" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        Text lenghts of Title and Author or even Description do not matter. They will all perfectly accommodate into .thumb on hover
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Yep. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate sequi aspernatur cumque saepe incidunt enim, nihil dolores ipsam numquam architecto velit labore quod laboriosam aliquam distinctio tempora unde ad totam.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumb">
    <img class="thumb-img" src="http://placekitten.com/290/340" alt="Catz!">
    <div class="thumb-gradient"></div>
    <div class="thumb-anim">
      <h3 class="thumb-title">The movie title</h3>
      <p class="thumb-description">
        Text lenghts of Title and Author or even Description do not matter. They will all perfectly accommodate into .thumb on hover
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-author">Published by super long some Author</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice, though an optional improvement would be to have the title end up at the same point regardless of content. Could be tricky without javascript though.

Comment: @jon I think it could be done by making the .anim also display flex, and on :hover set flex:1 to the title. But I see no visual benefit besides having inconsistent spaces between title and description...

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy with CSS transform...

```css
.thumbnail-component {
  width: 240px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail-component .text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(70%);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.thumbnail-component:hover .text {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-component">
  <img class="thumbnail-component__background" src="background.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="thumbnail-component__gradient"></div>
  <div class="text">

    <div class="text__content">
      <p class="text__title">The movie author</p>
      <div class="text__separator"></div>
      <p class="text__description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
      <p class="text__author">Published by Author</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and the author publisher is...? Not that easy, right? ;)

Comment: I'm talking about your answer not covering for the `text__author` bit.

Comment: ah yeah i did not account for that, sorry. I read it as difficulty animating from bottom only.

Answer (score 1):

You can transition on the `flex` property, which could be useful here. To reveal the description during the hover, I set its `opacity` to `0` and position it absolutely safely inside its relative parent container. Finally, I removed the `text__separator` `div` because it wasn't useful to be as a `flex` child.

```css
.text__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.text__content__top {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;
  transition: 0.5s flex ease-in-out;
}

.text__description {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s opacity ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.text__title {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}

.thumbnail-component:hover .text__content__top {
  flex: 1;
}

.thumbnail-component:hover .text__content__top > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.thumbnail-component:hover .text__description {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-component">
  <div class="text">
    <div class="text__content">

      <div class="text__content__top">
        <p class="text__title">The movie title</p>
        <p class="text__description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="text__content__bottom">
        <p class="text__author">Published by Author</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tcx7bhy/)

Comment: P.S: `.thumbnail-component:hover .text__content__top {` would be far better... Still, important to mention that `flex: 1;` will cover the entire height, not only the height needed to accommodate the text description exactly.

Comment: Also, why `min-height: 100vh;`? That's demo-purpose-cheating. Why not let the content than dictate the height necessary?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There are not many details provided. I read "bottom to top" and coded it the way I perceived OP's intent to be. Maybe I'm wrong. We'll see.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I took your suggestion on moving the `hover` to the top parent.

Comment: :) but you're still hacking by using some arbitrary `min-height: 100vh;` ;) I still think the height should be dictated by the content (+ eventually some extra space for design purpose)