# Hide and show text on an image JQuery, HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to all this, I hope you can help me. I have 5 images to which I superimposed text on each one. The idea is that the text is hidden and when you click on the image the text is shown and hidden in each image. The problem I have is that the text appears visible when the page loads. If I hide it using visibility: hidden in css. When you click on the image the text does not load.
On the other hand, I wanted to see if there is any way to improve the jquery code since I had to create one for each image so that they work separately, thank you very much in advance, excuse my English but I can handle myself with the translator.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZuTT.png)

***HTML AND JQUERY CODE, I HAVE IT TOGETHER TO TEST WITH MORE EASE***

```
<!--Contenedor Body-->
  <div class="contendor-general">

    <div class="contenedorSaquito">



      <div class="productoSaquitos" id="lata1">
        <div class="imagenSaquitos"><img src="imagenes/delhi-tea/saquitos/D-T-SAQ-AGUA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="textoSaquito" id="lata-t-1">
          <h5>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h5>
          <h6>Patagonia Finest Tea</h6>
          <h6>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</h6>
          <h6>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="productoSaquitos" id="lata2">
        <div class="imagenSaquitos"><img src="imagenes/delhi-tea/saquitos/D-T-SAQ-AIRE.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="textoSaquito" id="lata-t-2">
          <h5>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h5>
          <h6>Patagonia Finest Tea</h6>
          <h6>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</h6>
          <h6>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</h6>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="productoSaquitos" id="lata3">
        <div class="imagenSaquitos"><img src="imagenes/delhi-tea/saquitos/D-T-SAQ-CHOCO-&-ROSES.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="textoSaquito" id="lata-t-3">
          <h5>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h5>
          <h6>Patagonia Finest Tea</h6>
          <h6>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</h6>
          <h6>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</h6>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="productoSaquitos" id="lata4">
        <div class="imagenSaquitos"><img src="imagenes/delhi-tea/saquitos/D-T-SAQ-WILDBERRIES-&-HONEY.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="textoSaquito" id="lata-t-4">
          <h5>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h5>
          <h6>Patagonia Finest Tea</h6>
          <h6>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</h6>
          <h6>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</h6>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="productoSaquitos" id="lata5">
        <div class="imagenSaquitos"><img src="imagenes/delhi-tea/saquitos/D-T-SAQ-TIERRA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="textoSaquito" id="lata-t-5">
          <h5>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h5>
          <h6>Patagonia Finest Tea</h6>
          <h6>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</h6>
          <h6>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</h6>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  <!--Fin Contenedor Body-->
</div>
  <script src="js/finestea.js"></script>
  <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     
      $('#lata1').click(function (event) {

if ($('#lata-t-1').is(':visible')) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#lata-t-1').fadeOut(2000);
} else {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#lata-t-1').fadeIn(2000);
}

});

      $('#lata2').click(function (event) {

        if ($('#lata-t-2').is(':visible')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-2').fadeOut(2000);
        } else {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-2').fadeIn(2000);
        }

      });

      $('#lata3').click(function (event) {

        if ($('#lata-t-3').is(':visible')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-3').fadeOut(2000);
        } else {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-3').fadeIn(2000);
        }

      });

      $('#lata4').click(function (event) {

        if ($('#lata-t-4').is(':visible')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-4').fadeOut(2000);
        } else {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-4').fadeIn(2000);
        }

      });

      $('#lata5').click(function (event) {

        if ($('#lata-t-5').is(':visible')) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-5').fadeOut(2000);
        } else {
          event.preventDefault();
          $('#lata-t-5').fadeIn(2000);
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*QUITAMOS TODOS LOS BORDES*/
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }

  .contendor-general{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .contenedorSaquito{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-content: center;
  }

 .productoSaquitos{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }

 .imagenSaquitos{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
  
 }
 .imagenSaquitos img{
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
 
 .textoSaquito{
  width: 86%;
  height: 94%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
  
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .textoSaquito h6, h5{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.150em;
 }

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .productoSaquitos{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .textoSaquito{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why waste a user click in order to show a description over an image instead of navigating actually to that product page? On desktop I would instead use CSS `:hover` to show the (default hidden) thumbnail descriptions.

Comment: Don't use IDs. Use classes instead. Assign a click event listener to a class selector. In such case you need one function only. Use `$(this)` to handle the clicked one and a variable to handle any other element in the collection

Comment: PS No need to use `event.preventDefault();` if you don't use anchors or submit buttons...

Comment: PS if you want some inspiration see: [Animate card description on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55465997/383904)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript for that purpose. Use CSS `:focus` and `tabindex` like:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.contenedorSaquito {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .contenedorSaquito {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}

.productoSaquitos {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .productoSaquitos {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.imagenSaquitos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.textoSaquito {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: #000a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 0.8;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.productoSaquitos:focus .textoSaquito {
  opacity: 1;
  scale: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedorSaquito">

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoomR.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSFl8.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq32q.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also, I would propose not to waste clicks to show a card description, instead you could use CSS `:hover` like:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.contenedorSaquito {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .contenedorSaquito {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}

.productoSaquitos {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .productoSaquitos {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.imagenSaquitos {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.textoSaquito {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: #000a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 0.8;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.productoSaquitos:hover .textoSaquito {
  opacity: 1;
  scale: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedorSaquito">

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoomR.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSFl8.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="productoSaquitos" tabindex=0>
    <img class="imagenSaquitos" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq32q.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="textoSaquito">
      <h2>Ifusiones Arandano Azul</h2>
      <h3>Patagonia Finest Tea</h3>
      <p>Presentacion: 20 Saquitos</p>
      <p>Igrediente:Arandano y Cascara Naranja</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I have a question for you, sorry if it is very ignorant, but I am new to this. I wanted to do it with the click event so that when the user views the website on a cell phone they could also see the effect of the text appearing. Now I'm consulting you with the hover, can you also see the effect from the cell phone?