# How can I translate a child div from the bottom left to the top left of it's parent without it moving outside of the parent?

Tags: html, css, transform, parent-child

I'm trying to translate a .text-container from the bottom left to the top left of it's parent div on hover. I'm using percentages for the transform: translate(0, -100%);

This works in certain viewport sizes, but in other viewport sizes, the .text-container translates outside of it's parent div. Is there a way to contain the .text-container translation within the parent div?

Current code

```
<div class = "square-container">

<div class = "text-container">

<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

</div>

</div>
```

css

```
.text-container {

position: absolute;

bottom: 0;

left: 20px;

transition: transform 0.4s;

}

.square-container:hover .text-container {

transform: translate(0, -100%);

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Also that's not what a transform does. It moves the element 100% of **it's own size** not the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for the articles on posting; I've only posted once before, and those are really helpful. 

Do you have any alternate suggestions on how to achieve the outcome of the translation? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @edray You probably want to post the code for the `square-container` class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animate a div from bottom to top with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55465325/animate-a-div-from-bottom-to-top-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using 'top' instead of transform makes more sense. With transform element is moving up in its own height and not parent, hope this helps.

```css
.square-container {
position: relative; 
height: 200px; 
    
}

.text-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 20px;
    top: 120px; 
    transition: top 1s; 
}

.square-container:hover .text-container {
    top: 0; 
}
```

```html
<div class = "square-container">

<div class = "text-container">

<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is very helpful. Is there a way to animate that positioning from the bottom to the top over 0.4s? Right now with this solution it's jumping instantly from bottom to top.

Comment: @edray ya define top height which is now auto since top: auto is not animatable; I am editing my code to show you